# iTextSharp 5.5.6.0 Bug? check box tick mark changes

Tags: c#, itext

I have an existing PDF that I am filling in programmatically (C#).

There are check boxes on the form. In build 4.4.x they rendered a check mark when selected. In build 5.5.5.0 and 5.5.6.0 they are now a cross symbol.
The document has PdfVersion of 54 '6'.

I have tried:

```
SetFieldProperty(fieldname, "checkboxtype", RadioCheckField.TYPE_CHECK, null);
```

but with no luck.

Also I searched for the potential property list, but cannot seem to find a list of valid string values. Is the iText in Action -> Table 8.3 a complete listing?

Comment: Going from 4.4.x to 5.5.6 is a giant leap. Many changes are to be expected.

Comment: The code snippet in the question isn't supposed to work: there is no field property `"checkboxtype"`. Changing the checkboxtype involves changing the "on" and "off" appearances of the check box. I think the diagnosis is wrong. I think something else is at play; e.g. is the `Needappearances` value set in the PDF form? Actually: I think that iText 5.5.6 is showing the correct behavior whereas iText 4.4.x is doing it wrong. We should see the form to be sure.

Comment: Thanks for the response ! Unfortunately I can't post the form on a public forum (I could email to you). I am programmatically controlling the On/Off appearance of the tick mark. When the form is edited manually it is the correct "check" tickmark....so you comment is that the default symbol is a function of the form itself (is it dependent on an embedded font? I'll check the Needappearances value. The code and the form didn't change just the iText version.

Comment: iTextSharp 4.4.x does not exist and has never existed. Perhaps you are confusing with 4.2.0?

Answer (score 4):

I was having this exact problem.  If I manually filled out the PDF form in Adobe it put checkmarks, but if I used iTextSharp, it put crosses.  What worked for me to make iTextSharp put checkmarks was using:

```
SetField("checkbox name", "Yes", true);
```

The 'true' at the end changed it from a cross to a checkmark.  Hope that helps you.

Answer (score 1):

As other comments have stated, casting cannot be done on a PDF that was already created.

On the other hand, if you are filling out an existing PDF you can still change the check type of a ***CHECKBOX*** using Adobe Acrobat Pro. First, open the pdf with Adobe Acrobat Pro then click Tools-> Forms-> Edit then double click the field to open up the Field Properties, in this case Check Box Properties, then Options and change the "Check Box Style" to whatever you want.

In your code, use the lines:

```
AcroFields pdfFormFields = pdfStamper.AcroFields;
pdfFormFields.SetField("checkbox name", "Yes", true);
```

The "true" flag makes it so that iTextSharp uses the check box style that you chose when using Adobe Acrobat Pro.

Comment: *"You cannot programmatically change a "Check Box Style" of an already created pdf using iTextSharp."* - that's clearly wrong. You probably don't have a nice high-level method for it but you can use the low-level api here which allows arbitrary changes.

Comment: What is an example of this using iTextSharp?

Comment: As Bruno said in a comment to the original question, *Changing the checkboxtype involves changing the "on" and "off" appearances of the check box*. So all you need to do is (ex)change the appearance streams of the checkbox widgets.

Answer (score 0):

iTextSharp to get "Tick Mark" in PDF file. Please try the below one

```
form.SetField("Check Box1", "Yes",true);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//you can use this function but make sure to add the font wingdings
// just pass the table

  public static void AddCheckmarkCell(PdfPTable table)
            {

// Create a BaseFont for the Wingdings font
BaseFont wingdings = BaseFont.CreateFont(System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"\fonts\wingding.ttf", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);

                // Create a Font using the Wingdings font
                Font wingdingsFont = new Font(wingdings, 12);

                // Create a PdfPCell and set its content to the checkmark symbol
                PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("\u00FC", wingdingsFont)); // Checkmark symbol in Wingdings font

                // Set alignment for the cell
                cell.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE;
                cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;

                // Add the cell to the table
                table.AddCell(cell);
            }
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**